# How can I find the source of a communication object error when my stack trace is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

I have a C# .net program. I added a try/catch to a segment of code and am now getting an communication error.  The stack trace is empty, the server stack trace doesn't show any lines in my code, and the inner exception is empty.  The code inside the try/catch is about 100 lines.  How do I pinpoint the source of the error?

I didn't notice this error until I added the try/catch inside the handleShipmentBusinessRules method.

Here is the error message:

> Error Message: The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot
>   be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state. Stack
>   trace:  Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.BeginSend(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.BeginRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureOpen(IAsyncResult
>   result, Boolean completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureOpen(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.FinishEnsureInteractiveInit(IAsyncResult
>   result, Boolean completedSynchronously)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartEnsureInteractiveInit()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String
>   action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(ServiceChannel
>   channel, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6
>   beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2
>   arg2, TArg3 arg3, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2,TArg3](Func`6
>   beginMethod, Func`2 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3,
>   Object state)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.CreateGenericTask[T](ServiceChannel
>   channel, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] inputParameters)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.CreateGenericTask(ServiceChannel
>   channel, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] inputParameters)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.CreateTask(ServiceChannel
>   channel, IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeTaskService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   BusinessLogicLayer.ShipService.IShipService.ShippingMethods_GetByDishbooksCodeAsync(String
>   DishbooksCode)    at
>   BusinessLogicLayer.ShipmentsBLL.handleShipmentBusinessRules(Ship ship,
>   DishbooksOrder dbOrder) Inner exception:

Here is a part of the code:

```
public ShipmentDTO ProcessShipment(ShipAFilterDTO ShipAFilterDTO, bool TestShipment = false, bool RelieveInventory = true, bool AdjustGP = true, bool DeveloperMode = true)
{
        try
        {
            Ship ship = new Ship();
            ship = retrieveOrderDataIntoShipObject(ShipAFilterDTO);
            ship = shipClient.ProcessShipmentAsync(ship, TestShipment).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Voids the Shipment / Tracking Number, since something went wrong


shipClient.Shipment_VoidByTrackingNumberAsync(ship.TrackingNumber).Wait();
                       throw;
            }
        }

private Ship retrieveOrderDataIntoShipObject(ShipAFilterDTO ShipAFilterDTO)
{
    using (DishbooksUnitOfWork dbUnitOfWork = new DishbooksUnitOfWork(bllSettings.DishbooksConnectionString))
    {
        Ship ship = new Ship();

        ... Get some data here ...

        // Populate Ship
        ship.Notes = dbOrder.SpecialHandlingNotes + " ";
        ship.PackageNumber = 1;

        handleShipmentBusinessRules(ship, dbOrder);

            return ship;
    }
}


private void handleShipmentBusinessRules (Ship ship, DishbooksOrder dbOrder)
{
    try
    {
            if (dbOrder.IsWillCallOrder == true)
            {
                ship.ShippingCarrier = ShippingCarriers.Manual;
                ship.ShippingMethodCode = ShippingMethods.ManualShip;
                ship.Notes += "Will-Call - Please Take to NT Front-Desk ";
            }
            else if (dbOrder.IsFreight == true || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbOrder.RequestedShipper) && dbOrder.RequestedShipper.ToUpper() == "FREIGHT"))
            {
                ship.ShippingCarrier = ShippingCarriers.Manual;
                ship.ShippingMethodCode = ShippingMethods.ManualShip;
                ship.Notes += "Freight Order - Please Take to Freight Shipping Area ";
            }

        ... Additional populating of ship object

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(@"Error in ShipmentsBLL.cs/handleShipmentBusinessRules." +
                         Environment.NewLine + "Error Message: " + ex.Message +
                         Environment.NewLine + "Stack trace: " + ex.StackTrace +
                         Environment.NewLine + "Inner exception: " + ex.InnerException);
                throw;
    }
}
```

The Ship class is from a third party tool that takes the information passed from it and prints a shipping label.

Comment: What is dborder? What is it's scope?

Comment: What is `logger`? Is this `log4net`'s `ILogger` instance? If so change the logging statement to this: `logger.Error(@"Error in ShipmentsBLL.cs/handleShipmentBusinessRules.", ex);`, this will capture all the detail of the exception. You do need to ensure that the output appender is configured to display everything though, check their documentation site for a good config (example [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender))

Comment: dborder is a class that stores data from SQL.  The DAL has it's own error handling, so it's not a concern.

Comment: logger is using nlogger.  It just logs the exception to a text file.  It generated the log I included in my question.

Comment: Then see the [documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions). You should log your exceptions like `logger.Error(ex, @"Error in ShipmentsBLL.cs/handleShipmentBusinessRules.");`. That should include everything you need to the output. No reason to try to break apart the exception parts and create your own exception string for logging.

Comment: Just including the exception doesn't show any messages or stack trace.  logger.Error(ex, @"Error in ShipmentsBLL.cs/handleshipmentBusinessRules."); just shows "2019-05-03 12:29:46.9942 ERROR Error in ShipmentsBLL.cs/handleshipmentBusinessRules."  This is why I specifically was trying to include the message, stack trace, and inner exception.